# Accessing attributes of dynamically created elements using .on function and selector paramter

Tags: jquery

I have elements that are dynamically created and I want to access attributes of one of them after it has been clicked.  I want to identify these new child elements based on their class name.  From what I understand, I should use the .on function to add a click handler using a parent element that already exists.  For example, this would be the dynamic elements:

```
<div id="parent">
    <a class="dynamicChild" id="123" />
    <a class="dynamicChild" id="124" />
    <a class="dynamicChild" id="125" />
</div>
```

And this the function to add a click handler:

```
$('#parent').on('click', '.dynamicChild', function(e) { });
```

My question is, within the above function I want to access the id of the child element that was clicked.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might do this?  My guess was the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
alert($(this).id);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `alert($(this).attr('id'));` http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap it up just yet:

```
this.id // should work
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6J9E/) with your exact same code!

And if for some reason you already have it turned into a jQuery object, you'll have to get the attribute explicitly:

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

Yet another alternative:

```
e.target.id
```

Comment: Thanks! :) Slightly embarrassed that the answer is so straightforward.  Although I appreciate it.